# process popup on ajax and don't display on html

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have a bit of a problem . I can succesfully sort my date range now but the problem is that it doesn't display on my datatable it's always has this process popup box

[image]

But i have the data as you can see here on the image below

[image]

I am using `CodeIgniter 3.x` by the way.
Here's my code

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
todayBtn: 'linked',
format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
autoclose: true
});

function fetch_data(start_date='', end_date=''){
var dataTable = $('#table-sales').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order":[],
    "ajax":{
        url: "sales/rangeDates",
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            'start_date':start_date, 'end_date':end_date
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#table-sales').html(data);
        }
    }
});
}

$('#search').click(function(){

var inv_type = $('#invType').val();
var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
var end_date = $('#end_date').val();


if(start_date != '' && end_date != '' && inv_type != 0){
    $('#table-sales').DataTable().destroy();
    fetch_data(start_date,end_date);
}else{
    alert('Both Date is Required and Choose what to show!');
}

});
```

Please let me know if there's a missing information I need to show you guys. Thank you.

## RESPONSE:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your fetch data code

```
function fetch_data(start_date='', end_date=''){
var dataTable = $('#table-sales').DataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"order":[],
"ajax":{
    url: "sales/rangeDates",
    type: "POST",
    data:{
        'start_date':start_date, 'end_date':end_date
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('#table-sales').html(data);
        $("#table-sales_processing").css("visibility","hidden");
    }
 }
});
}
```

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem at all it just hide the processing pop up sir but couldn't fetch data

Comment: Have you check what he return in response?

Comment: How to check the return in response sir? but if you are talking about on the devtool here's the response `[{"id":"1","inv_type":"1","inv_cno":"1418","custid":"2","cust_name":"45 ENTERPRISES","inv_price":"444","inv_tax":"0","pay_due":"2018-12-08","payment":null,"timestamp":"2018-11-08 19:24:31"},{"id":"8","inv_type":"4","inv_cno":"UT-1418","custid":"3","cust_name":"ACE ANG","inv_price":"15000","inv_tax":"0","pay_due":"2018-12-16","payment":"1000","timestamp":"2018-11-10 00:00:00"}]`

Comment: using inspect element have use before use it?

Comment: insted fo $('#table-sales').html(data); this line you need to prepare table here then append to $('#table-sales')

Comment: Edited my question sir please kindly take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183924/discussion-between-boonmingprog-and-sachin).

Comment: so it's like `$('table-sales').append(data);` ??

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: There's no more problem solved it . Thank you sachin